# Cronjob for automatic email?

Tags: php, cron, sendmail

I'm not sure what to do.

I have to tabels, one with user emails and one with upcoming events.

The event table contains a date for when the event is going to happen, and i wanna notify the user who is attending the event via email.

should i make a cron job? or is there another and better way to do it?

Comment: is there a specific time when you want to send the email??

Comment: Ooh yes sorry, i wanna send the email 24 hours before the event date

Comment: you can use cronjob for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a cronjob for this, yes. If you want to notify the users one day prior to the event, you can just add a cronjob that runs daily and checks all events for the next day, something like:

```
<?php
$tomorrowsEvents = $databaseResultsHere; // Insert actual db results here ;-)
foreach ($tomorrowsEvents as $event) {
    $attendees = $attendeesFromDatabase; // Also insert a real db result here
    foreach ($attendees as $attendee) {
        mail($attendee['email'], 'Your event is tomorrow', 'Have fun!');
    }
}
```

Just run that daily and you can simply mail all your users at that moment.